# Numpy isin() is not returning expected result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Based on the code below, I would expect the first element of the 'duplicate' column to return 'True' since it exists in 'df_set'. This is for a much larger data-set, hence the use of converting to a set...

What am I doing incorrectly that is causing the first element of 'duplicate' to return 'False?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['tom', 'juli'],
    ['nick', 'heather'],
    ['juli', 'john'],
    ['dustin', 'tracy']
]
columns = ['Name', 'Name2']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
df_set = set(df['Name'])
df['duplicate'] = np.isin(df['Name2'], df_set, assume_unique=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Name    Name2  duplicate
0     tom     juli      False
1    nick  heather      False
2    juli     john      False
3  dustin    tracy      False
```

Comment: another option would be to use `df['duplicate'] = df['Name2'].isin(df_set)`

Answer (score 5):

numpy doesn't seem to like sets, so you should convert the set back to a list:

```
df['duplicate'] = np.isin(df['Name2'], list(df_set), assume_unique=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     Name    Name2  duplicate
0     tom     juli       True
1    nick  heather      False
2    juli     john      False
3  dustin    tracy      False
```

Comment: `np.isin` uses `np.in1d`, which applies `np.asarray` and `ravel` to the inputs, concatenates them, and then does an `argsort`.  This puts duplicates together.  `np.asarray(df_set)` makes a 1 element object dtype array.  `numpy` set functions are not particularly fast or sophisticated.  And they nearly always first convert the inputs into arrays, so we need to take that into account.

Comment: `np.isin(df['Name2'], df['Name'])` .  Using `set` on `Name` doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, could still evaluate within df;

```
df['duplicate'] =df['Name2'].isin(set(df['Name']))



     Name    Name2  duplicate
0     tom     juli       True
1    nick  heather      False
2    juli     john      False
3  dustin    tracy      False
```

Comment: I though of this too, but looking at some benchmarks, this actually seems 2+ times slower! ??

Comment: You are right @richard, was just tapping in when I realized you already had answered. resorted to alternative :-)

Comment: It's definitely nicer-looking though. I'm a bit surprised that pandas doesn't use numpy underneath more...or maybe it's doing more type/error checking...

Comment: This `pandas` method returns a `Series`, while the `np.isin` returns an array.  Constructing a `Series` (or `DataFrame`) has a significant overhead. @richardec